# How to force the OpenFileDialog to be opened at a certain location across all the OS from my WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, openfiledialog

Is it possible, from my WPF application, to set the prefered location that the Windows OpenFileDialog will be opened at, no matter which application will fire it, if it possible how can I achieve that ?

Comment: How are you creating and displaying the dialog box?

Comment: @JimMischel: Not creating it, no displaying it, that's exactly my problem, I want within my app to set that location without interrupting the user by opening a "OpenFileDialog" that he doesn't need

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to force the initial directory for the open file dialog, regardless of which program displays it. So if somebody starts Notepad or Excel or any other application and elects to open a file, the initial directory will be the same--the one that you specified in some global setting. I know of no such setting.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes that's exactly what I want, is there anyway to achieve that ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. I guess it's possible that you could write a driver that hooks the API calls that open the dialog, but I don't know how well that would work. What you're asking is kind of unusual. What is the bigger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JimMischel It's not really a big problem, just an option I want to add to an application that Im' developing

Answer (score 0):

Open Dialog position can not set in WPF so you need to create the custom open Dialog box in a WPF form and then you can set the position or margins of the WPF form accordingly.

Comment: I'm not talking about the position of the window, I'm talking about the initial location (path) of the OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`, you can set the `InitialDirectory` property on the dialog before opening.